# TypeScript - How to design a type class that dynamically takes on the characteristics of another class?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to design a wrapper class that is able to dynamically take on the properties of another class (or even interface); for example...

```
interface Person {
    readonly firstName: string;
    readonly lastName: string;
    readonly birthday?: Date
}

class Wrapper<T> {
    public constructor(template: T) {
        ...
    }

    public foo(): void {
        ...
    }

    public bar(): void {
        ...
    }
}

const p: Wrapper<Person> = new Wrapper({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith"
});

p.foo() // okay
p.bar() // okay
p.firstName // compiler error, property does not exist in Wrapper<T>
```

Is there a way to instruct the compiler that `Wrapper<T>` also includes the properties of `T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by adding a union type of the wrapper and the template:

```
type Wrapped<T> = Wrapper<T> & T;
```

Since the constructor for `Wrapper<T>` can only return `Wrapper<T>`, I've also included a static method to construct instances of `Wrapped<T>`:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    constructor(template: T) {
        ...
    }

    public foo() { ... }

    public static fromTemplate(template: T): Wrapped<T> {
        return new Wrapper<T>(template) as Wrapped<T>;
    }
}

const x: Wrapped<Person> = Wrapper.fromTemplate({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    age: 33
});

x.foo() // okay
x.firstName // okay
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a factory, something like this:

```
function WrapperFactory<T>(template: T): Wrapper<T> & T {
  return new Wrapper(template) as Wrapper<T> & T;
}

const p = WrapperFactory<Person>({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith'
});

p.bar(); // ok
p.firstName; // ok
```

However I'd imagine there will be some trouble with interacting with those additional fields coming from template in your class, but I don't know if that's an issue in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it with the following ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=99&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=48&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqBOYAOSCm8A8AVAfNA3gLABQ0Z0EALmJQJbDTDyo2rY4AUlqAtkuNwBc0LAEphCZGky5oAMhEES5FYwD2AOyrRq8AOapK0ALzQNqAO5xEKdF179WogNzLVZYJu0Q1AV3jAqCY6DgJBkNBgGgCerqTu0ADyAEYAVqjAlAB0ANao0RD2fGGiWQBmavAAomDAABYcedEmeETxCeQp6ZlZACaoZbTmAArwatKU0Vxg+oYANNBNC20dHQaUwhyiLRR+AagA2k0AunNuq6oQhsIAbmAgvkHGrbv+gUf5x8F3D0EAvudVn9RICVMC4qDyMxKP4NDoZutIjAorFAQDiICkPBaHduNAAPrcYqsYRYCHtaBYnGsdRaSjwXyZSpFRxCETbFYJSh1WgQLKE0I00xE1moOJgkiAipqLa3NS0XoEWk+ECoLIgNR6DgAcml2pc0HRKmSM1l0Bu8sV+GValV6s1OpN8H1zkNJHRJCG3HgZVqQWG6B8cM5ZGYYF6mhAzUG8CoADkwDxUMIqNiNHpxVCWBGNFHoOB44nkxR6UMM4Cwzm88laPBub0wNEAPzCAAirHdkuIAHpu9ALLRudBUAAPfj0QfQAzmbHAEieOn9mxoXoB2OaYKSWzwLJMFjcDBroOcEPQGOFpPCABEACk1HUNFezhSC5QE5foFeAMo8Qd1K-ui4XYWMuqCroGmjlGoMpAcQC4qmqGpaiBUhgUekHnm+RYLChtjgeuGjqpAWFJjhoH4UGWQ1nWdQNtEsEkL2-Z-jo0RoNAQxlOgqAaIE0Dzl4Ri4SuXQZEYphbtIu5htwHCnph77FleACCIBPoCr6KdeADizA8QBxDgsB5GiT0TpbHE8G2ohDrCWBpnZAp2FLqhvQOURF6oLBQA)).

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    static create<T>(template: T): Wrapper<T> & T {
        const target = new Wrapper(template);
        const source = template as any;
        Object.keys(template).forEach(key => {
            Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
                get: () => source[key],
                set: value => { source[key] = value }
            })
        });

        return target as any;
    }

    private _template: T;

    private constructor(template: T) {
        this._template = template;
    }

    foo(): void { console.log('foo'); }
    bar(): void { console.log('bar'); }
}

interface Person {
    readonly firstName: string;
    readonly lastName: string;
    readonly birthday?: Date
}

// with explicit generic
const wrappedPerson = Wrapper.create<Person>({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith"
});

wrappedPerson.foo();
console.log(wrappedPerson.firstName, wrappedPerson.lastName, wrappedPerson.birthday);

// with type inference 
const wrappedObject = Wrapper.create({
    firstName: "Al",
    lastName: "Green"
});

wrappedObject.bar();
console.log(wrappedObject.firstName, wrappedObject.lastName);
```

In this example, the `create` method dynamically creates get/set accessors on the wrapper object with `Object.defineProperty` that delegates to the *template*.

This is the generated JavaScript:

```js
class Wrapper {
    constructor(template) {
        this._template = template;
    }
    static create(template) {
        const target = new Wrapper(template);
        const source = template;
        Object.keys(template).forEach(key => {
            Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
                get: () => source[key],
                set: value => { source[key] = value; }
            });
        });
        return target;
    }
    foo() { console.log('foo'); }
    bar() { console.log('bar'); }
}
// with explicit generic
const wrappedPerson = Wrapper.create({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith"
});
wrappedPerson.foo();
console.log(wrappedPerson.firstName, wrappedPerson.lastName, wrappedPerson.birthday);
// with type inference 
const wrappedObject = Wrapper.create({
    firstName: "Al",
    lastName: "Green"
});
wrappedObject.bar();
console.log(wrappedObject.firstName, wrappedObject.lastName);
```